# What are possible values for commonj.sdo.DataObject.getList when retrieving LDAP data on WebSphere

Tags: java, virtual-member-manager

using as reference the code at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/samplecodeforsearchbasedonextendedpropertyvalue.html

I have the following piece of code:

```
searchCtrl.getList(SchemaConstants.PROP_PROPERTIES).add("uid");
searchCtrl.getList(SchemaConstants.PROP_PROPERTIES).add("sn");
searchCtrl.getList(SchemaConstants.PROP_PROPERTIES).add("cn");
searchCtrl.getList(SchemaConstants.PROP_PROPERTIES).add("age");
```

I'm trying to return other LDAP properties (sAMAccountName and distringuishedName) but both aren't returned if I add then to the code above. For the search I'm doing, I'm sure that the users returned has sAMAccountName and distinguishedName properties. Any reason to not have success returning the properties that I need? Can any LDAP properties be returned using IBM Virtual Member Manager?

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I published an article that explains how to access custom LDAP attributes using VMM:

http://veithen.github.io/2012/12/13/retrieving-custom-user-attributes-from.html